# An error occurred while processing this request wcf Data service

Tags: c#, mysql, wcf

This is my web.config code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SupplierProjectEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/SupplierDatabase.csdl|res://*/SupplierDatabase.ssdl|res://*/SupplierDatabase.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=127.0.0.1;User Id=root;password=sa_12345;database=supplier&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This is my WCF data service Code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web;

namespace SupplierService
{
    public class SupplierProjectService : DataService<SupplierProjectEntities >
    {
        // This method is called only once to initialize service-wide policies.
        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            // TODO: set rules to indicate which entity sets and service operations are visible, updatable, etc.
            // Examples:
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
        }
    }
}
```

Error description.
When i am running this wcf data service then i am getting error as below.

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code/>
<message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
<innererror>
<message>
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
</message>
<type>System.NullReferenceException</type>
<stacktrace>
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.get_MySqlDbProviderServicesInstance()
 at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory.System.IServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType)
 at System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderServices(DbProviderFactory factory)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.InitializeProviderManifest(Action`3 addError)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.OnProviderManifestTokenNotification(String token, Action`3 addError)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleProviderManifestTokenAttribute(XmlReader reader)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleAttribute(XmlReader reader)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.ParseAttribute(XmlReader reader)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaElement.Parse(XmlReader reader)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.HandleTopLevelSchemaElement(XmlReader reader)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.InternalParse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
 at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Loader.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest, DbProviderFactory& providerFactory, String& providerManifestToken, Memoizer`2& cachedCTypeFunction)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.StoreItemCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreMetadataEntry.LoadStoreCollection(EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.StoreItemCollectionLoader.LoadItemCollection(StoreMetadataEntry entry)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry)
 at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateStoreAndMappingItemCollections(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, Object& entryToken)
 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.LoadStoreItemCollections(MetadataWorkspace workspace, DbConnection storeConnection, DbProviderFactory factory, DbConnectionOptions connectionOptions, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection, MetadataArtifactLoader artifactLoader)
 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.InitializeMetadata(DbConnection newConnection, DbConnection originalConnection, Boolean closeOriginalConnectionOnFailure)
 at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetEnumeratorInternal()
 at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
 at System.Data.Services.WebUtil.GetRequestEnumerator(IEnumerable enumerable)
 at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
 at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description)
 at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
</stacktrace>
</innererror>
</error>
```

Explanation of Error.
This database i had first made in sql server.and when i had made wcf data service for sql server then it was working properly.and that database was as same as mysql database.
but now have made WCF data service for mysql database then i am getting this error. 
as shown above.so please help me for this error it's argent to solve this error.

I am asking this question to retrieve data from mysql database it's version is 6.7.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the answer of my question.

The answer is that i had just forgot to add **Mysql.data.dll** and **mysql.data.entity.dll** 
in **reference** folder.
so after adding this dll in reference folder i could solved above error 
so you can also try.
i hope it will be helpful.